# Cycles that are graphs of morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Assume we have an irreducible algebraic cycle $Z$ on $X\times Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are projective varieties ($X$ is smooth) such that restriction of $Z$ to $U\times Y$ where $U\subset X$ is a Zariski open is a graph of a regular map from $U$ to $Y$. Is any cycle close enough to $Z$ on the Chow variety also graph of a morphism when restricted to $U\times Y$? In other words is the family of irreducible cycles with the aforementioned property a Zariski open subset of the Chow variety?

It seems that one can modify the proof of the fact $\text{Hom}$ scheme is an open sub-scheme of the Hilbert scheme to this setting, I just wanted to make sure this is correct and whether there is a simpler proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as stated. Let $X$ be $\mathbb P^2$, $Y$ be the blowup of $\mathbb P^2$ on one point $P$, $Z$ the graph of the blowup map $Y \to X$, which is the graph of a regular map on the open set $U$ defined as the complement of $P$.

We can deform $Z$ in a family that moves the point $P$. The cycles in that family will each be regular on some open set, but it won't be the same open set $U$.

Allowing $U$ to vary, the answer is positive, since this occurs if and only if the intersection number of $Z$ with a general fiber of the projection to $X$ is $1$, and that's an open (and closed) condition in the Chow variety.

Comment: BTW your $X$ and $Y$ are switched morphisms are supposed to be from $X$ to $Y$. If I understand correctly, you are claiming that even we assume $U=Y$ (the exact analogue of the Hilbert scheme situation for Chow varieties) is not true? Because in your case $Z$ is a graph on the whole $Y$ and any cycle close to it is not necessarily a graph on the whole thing. (because if it was it would have been a graph on $U$ too)

Comment: @user127776 No, I didn't switch them. I'm considering a cycle which is the graph of a morphism from $Y $ to $ X$ which also happens to be "almost" the graph of a morphism from $X $ to $Y$, because the original morphism is "almost" an isomorphism.

Comment: Just wondering, do you think this is still false if we assume $U=X$?

Comment: @user127776 If $U=X$ it's an open condition. For $C$ the Chow variety, the locus in $C \times X$ where the universal cycle in $C \times X \times Y$ has one-point fibers is open (it's the locus where the fiber has dimension 0, now apply general semicontinuity for proper morphisms) and you're looking at the complement of the projection to $C$ of the complement of that open set, which is open by properness of $X$.